# How can you dynamically set binding path in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a `ContentControl` with `ItemSource` set to a collection of `Panel`s. I want to make a `DataTemplate` where the `DataContext` is set to a `Panel`. The `Panel` has a public property `Receiver`, which is an object that receives data. The class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface such that when its public property `Parameters` is finished updating, the `PropertyChanged` event is fired and the parameters are updated. The content of the panel should be the corresponding property which is given by the `ParameterType` (an enum containing `Param1` and `Param2`), which in itself is a property of the `Panel` object.

Panel.cs

```
public class Panel : BindableBase
{
    private Receiver _receiver;
    private PanelType _parameterType;

    public Panel(Receiver receiver, PanelType parameterType)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
        _parameterType = parameterType;

    }

    public Receiver CurrentReceiver
    {
        get { return _receiver; }
    }

    public PanelType ParameterType
    {
        get { return _parameterType; }
    }

}
```

Receiver.cs

```
public class Receiver : BindableBase
{
    ...

    public void Read()
    {
        // Receive some data
        Parameters.Param1 = 1;
        Parameters.Param2 = 5;

        // NotifyPropertyChanged (via Prism: RaisePropertyChanged())
        RaisePropertyChanged("Parameters");
    }

    public Params Parameters {get; set;}

    ...

}
```

Params.cs

```
public class Params : BindableBase
{
    public Params(int param1, int param2)
    {
        Param1 = param1;
        Param2 = param2;
    }

    public int Param1 {get; set;}
    public int Param2 {get; set;}

}
```

As the Receiver notifies of its property `Parameters` which is changed, I want my interface to update whenever this property is changed. This is working for me, whenever I bind in my `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentReceiver.Parameters.Param1}" />
```

The control is updated whenever new data is read.

However, I am using this control inside of a `DataTemplate` which has the `Panel` as `DataContext`, and I would like to bind to something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentReceiver.Parameters.{Binding ParameterType}}" />
```

But obviously, that does not work. I tried using a multi binding in combination with a multi-value converter which returns a `PropertyPath` to use, but had no success in doing so. Dynamically constructing the `Path` by binding the `ParameterType` to it does not work, as `Path` is not a `DependencyProperty`. (I read that this has to do with compile-time vs. runtime, which is why I tried the multi-value converter approach)

I have gotten this to work earlier (when not using `DataTemplate`) by setting the `Binding` in the code-behind:

```
...
valueTextBlock.SetBinding(
    TextBlock.TextProperty,
    new Binding("CurrentReceiver.Parameters." + Title)
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        StringFormat = "0.00"
    });
...
```

But (I think) that approach is not available (and not desirable) when using `DataTemplate`. Can anyone help me out and point me in the right direction?

Kind regards,

Tom

Comment: You may add a property to the Panel class which simply returns the current parameter, i.e. either CurrentReceiver.Parameters.Param1 or CurrentReceiver.Parameters.Param2. The Panel class could attach a PropertyChanged handler to its CurrentReceiver to be notified when it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BindableBase class must have a method for assigning a value to a property: Set (ref ...) or SetProperty (ref ..).
If I understand your task correctly, then look at such an implementation.

**Class Params:**

```
public class Params : BindableBase
{
    public Params() { }

    public Params(int param1, int param2)
    {
        Param1 = param1;
        Param2 = param2;
    }

    private int _param1;
    private int _param2;
    public int Param1 { get => _param1; set => Set(ref _param1, value); }
    public int Param2 { get => _param2; set => Set(ref _param2, value); }
}
```

**Class Receiver:**

```
public class Receiver : BindableBase
{

    public void Read()
    {
        // Receive some data
        Parameters.Param1 = 1;
        Parameters.Param2 = 5;

        // NotifyPropertyChanged (via Prism: RaisePropertyChanged())
        // RaisePropertyChanged("Parameters");
    }

    private Params _parameters;
    public Params Parameters { get => _parameters; set => Set(ref _parameters, value); }

}
```

**Class Panel:**

```
public enum PanelType { Param1, Param2 }
public class Panel : BindableBase
{

    public Panel(Receiver currentReceiver, PanelType parameterType)
    {
        CurrentReceiver = currentReceiver;
        ParameterType = parameterType;

        CurrentReceiver.PropertyChanged += CurrentReceiver_PropertyChanged;
        CurrentReceiver.RaisePropertyChanged(null);
    }

    private void CurrentReceiver_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parameters != CurrentReceiver.Parameters)
        {
            if (Parameters != null)
                Parameters.PropertyChanged -= Parameters_PropertyChanged;

            Parameters = CurrentReceiver.Parameters;

            if (Parameters != null)
            {
                Parameters.PropertyChanged += Parameters_PropertyChanged;
                Parameters.RaisePropertyChanged(null);
            }
            else
                CurentValue = null;
        }
    }

    private void Parameters_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (ParameterType)
        {
            case PanelType.Param1:
                CurrentValue = Parameters.Param1;
                break;
            case PanelType.Param2:
                CurrentValue = Parameters.Param2;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public Receiver CurrentReceiver { get; }

    public PanelType ParameterType { get; }

    private Params Parameters;

    // If the type is always the same and known in advance, 
    // then «object» must be replaced with a known type.
    private object _currentValue;
    public object CurrentValue { get => _currentValue; private set => Set(ref _currentValue, value); }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentValue}" />
```

And you chose a very bad name for the Panel class.
Involuntarily there is an association with System.Windows.Controls.Panel and this is confusing.